# Getting the right discount rate with goal seek in Python

Tags: python

I have a present value calculation with a given discount rate.
However, I also have a target value for this calculation.
Here is a very simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
disc = 1.04
df = pd.DataFrame({'Income':[100*1.08**i for i in range(5)],
'Discount_vector':[disc**(-i) for i in range(5)]})
df['PV of CF'] = df['Income'] * df['Discount_vector']
x = df['PV of CF'].sum()
target = 545
```

What I would like is to minimize the difference between target and x by changing the value of the discount rate (i.e. disc).
I would be grateful if you could help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use min search function fmin from [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) after converting requirements to a function.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def f(disc):
    ' Create function that calculates error between x and target '
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Income':[100*1.08**i for i in range(5)], 
                       'Discount_vector':[disc**(-i) for i in range(5)]})

    df['PV of CF'] = df['Income'] * df['Discount_vector']
    x = df['PV of CF'].sum()
    
    target = 545
    error = x - target
    return error**2            # Returning squared error
```

**Usage**

```
# Starting discount rate
start = 1.04

# Find min of f starting at start
start = 1.04
discount = fmin(f, [start]) 

print(f'Discount = {discount}')
```

**Output**

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000035
         Iterations: 13
         Function evaluations: 26
Discount = [1.03537891]
```

Thus, Discount needed was 1.03537891

Comment: Hi Darryl,
This is brilliant.